# Bottom with url

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am working with a twitter bootstrap bottom, but having the issue that the url shows as link in the bottom. How can I make the bottom be the link?

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">{{ HTML::linkRoute('create_user', 'Opprett bruker') }}   </button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want this

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute('create_user', 'Opprett bruker', array(), array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) }}
```

There's no need for an actual button tag in your case.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" href="{{route('create_user')}}">Opprett bruker</button>
```

Comment: Bottom doesn't with, i dont think href is the right way.

Comment: It is right, but maybe there is a better solution.the botton was not showing correctly because the linkroute function generate an anchor tag <a></a> that mean you will have a link inside the button